# window.open(url) overtakes window of previous window.open(url)

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a Javascript front-end, and a Java backend.

The Java backend supplies links to documents which can be viewed inline (we use the query parameter 'download=false' for inline viewing).

In Javascript, the following happens:

**click on button for document 1**

```
window.open("example.com:50000/my/api/document/1/binary?download=false")
```

*browser opens new window successfully, and displays content in new window*

**click on button for document 2**

```
window.open("example.com:50000/my/api/document/2/binary?download=false")
```

*browser replaces the content of the previously opened new window with the new content, instead of opening a new third window*

How do I get Javascript to open a new third window, rather than change the second window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a second argument to `window.open`, e.g. a current date would always open a new window.

```
window.open('https://...', Date.now());
```

Comment: See also an article at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open